# Update and OnRowUpdating

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In Default.aspx AutoGenerateEditButton enables the "Edit" buttons along the first column (OnRowEditing) When you press the  "Edit" Button it brings up two more buttons: Update (OnRowUpdating) and Cancel (OnRowCancelingEdit).  I need help with the "Update" Button and the Data that goes in the SQL Statement.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowCancelingEdit="Gridview1_OnRowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="Gridview1_OnRowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_OnRowUpdating>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In Default.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub GridView1_OnRowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    ViewState("pageIndex") = GridView1.EditIndex
    ShowGrid()
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_OnRowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    ViewState("pageIndex") = GridView1.EditIndex
    ShowGrid()
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_OnRowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
    Dim connStr, cmdStr As String
    connStr = "Connection String works"
    cmdStr = "UPDATE table1 SET (col2=@col2,col3=@col3,col4=@col4) WHERE id=@id;"
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col3", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col4", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception


    End Try
    ShowGrid()
End Sub
```

I am not sure about the lines of code:

GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text)

What does this mean the row where you selected "Edit" then edit entry then press Update

What is the column "Cell(1)" 1 for first column?

What is the column "Cell(2)" 2 is for the second column?

id is in col1 and is the Primary Key so if it is changed it should go to the bottom of the stack.

When I update a column it automatically reverts to the old value.

Comment: Make sure that if you are calling `ShowGrid()` in Page_Load, it is inside any `If Not IsPostBack ... EndIf` block.

Answer (score 0):

`e.RowIndex` indicates the index of the row being edited and it's zero-based. For example 0 means the first row, 1 means the second row, and so on.

`GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text` means the text of a certain column and `Cells(i)` is also zero-based like `e.RowIndex`. For example if `e.RowIndex` value is 0, then `GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text` will return the text of the first row and second column. The same thing applies to `GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text`, it will return the text of the first row and third column.

I think you probably passed the wrong value to `@id` parameter and the update statement didn't update anything since the value wasn't found in the database.

Since you said "id is in col1 and is the Primary Key", I'd guess this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text)
```

should be changed to this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text)
```